# Custom wordpress plugin shows update for new blank plugin

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to fix this issue when building custom wordpress plugins?

The file directory is `plugins/twitter/autoload.php` with the `autoload.php` containing the following items:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Twitter
 * Description: Showcase Twitter feed using Gutenberg Blocks.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Test
 */
```

Does anyone know why my custom plugin with nothing inside of it yet is showing that it needs an update? When I update the plugin, it grabs files from some other twitter plugin and overwrites all of my files.

[image]

Is there a naming issue? Can two plugins not have the same name? This was't an issue when I was building an Instagram plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress updates pull from the WordPress plugin repo and this means it matches and existing one. You need to rename the folder to avoid this.

You can also click on the View version details to see what it is matching against.

Comment: As Mark says there's already a plugin that uses the `twitter` slug. See [Twitter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter/). Follow Mark's suggestion and rename your plugin's folder to something else, OP.

Comment: Thanks all! I will go ahead and rename the folder.

Comment: You're welcome. This also goes for Themes